# Sorting and filtering is broken on /questions

Tags: bug, questions

### Sorting error

When querying [/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) and sort them by creation in descending order, the `creation_date` drops very rapidly.

I was looking for questions in the [php] tag on Stack Overflow. There are over 1000 php questions asked today, but I received questions that were asked 2 years ago when I get to about 400 items.

[This query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=5&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=php&filter=!--KJB7K%29teh_&site=stackoverflow&run=true) reveals that they are not really sorted by `creation_date` at all:

[image: Sorting error]

Plotting the `creation_date` of the first 700 items produces the following graph. You can see there is a weird drop in `creation_date` all the way to 2008 before going back to normal again.

[image: graph]

This problem isn't always present though. I encountered this issue at around 3:45 PM UTC for two days in a row but not during other times of the day.

### Filtering error

Another problem with /questions is that if I specify `fromdate`, `todate`, `min` or `max` when sort by creation, it no longer returns any negatively scored questions.

With [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=php&filter=!--KJAf%287F_KK&site=stackoverflow&run=true), I was able to find the typical bad questions in the [php] tag. However, [specifying the `fromdate`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2014-05-21&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=php&filter=!--KJAf%287F_KK&site=stackoverflow&run=true) has a side-effect of eliminating all the bad questions (click on the image to enlarge):

[image: Filtering error]